# How to configure the mail channel of a QnA Bot?

Tags: email, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm working in a bot that uses a QnA Service to answer some questions. I set up channels like mail or Microsoft Teams so the bot can respond the answers there. I wanted to configure the mail channel so it responds if the subject is a particular one.

I don't see any option to configure it where you link the bot to the mail channel:

[image]

Is there any way to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email channel configuration with the bot and making your logic work are two different things.

- First, you need to link your bot to the email channel by entering your Office 365 email credentials and click on 'Save'. The screenshot which you have attached above just needs you to enter your credentials which would connect your QnA Bot to your email account.
- Now, on to the part where you want the bot to respond if the subject line is a particular one. That basically means that you will be checking the **channel data** to see if the subject line is saved, then checking that the subject line contains a certain word or a sentence and if it does, then respond.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) documentation will enable you to pass native metadata to a channel in the activity object's channel data property.

For example,the JSON object of the channelData property for a custom email message is shown below:

```
"channelData": {
    "type": "message",
    "locale": "en-Us",
    "channelID": "email",
    "from": { "id": "mybot@mydomain.com", "name": "My bot"},
    "recipient": { "id": "joe@otherdomain.com", "name": "Joe Doe"},
    "conversation": { "id": "123123123123", "topic": "awesome chat" },
    "channelData":
    {
        "htmlBody": "<html><body style = /"font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;/" >This is more than awesome.</body></html>",
        "subject": "Super awesome message subject",
        "importance": "high",
        "ccRecipients": "abcdef@xxx.com"
    }
}
```

An example to set Email channel specific properties in ChannelData can be implemented such as:

```
 if (message.ChannelId == ChannelIds.Email)
{
    var reply = message.CreateReply();
    reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
    {
        htmlBody = "<html><body style=\"font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;\">This is the email body!</body></html>",
        subject = "This is the email subject",
        importance = "high"
    });
    //send reply to user
    await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where can I put the code to filter the answers given if the reply comes from the email channel in the QnA Service Bot? I'm not very familiar with the code that Azure does for you and I don't know where would b the correct place for it

Comment: The above example I have provided is an example of a Dialog replying to an email where it checks for the channel Id and if it is equal to the email channel, then it will send the response. You would need to customize your code by modifying the channel data. A good starting point would be [this](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/03/28/custom-channel-data/) documentation.